# C# MVC - Declare a list of objects in method returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I am attempting to add a model to a list of this model in another model but am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Donor_Pledges.get returned null.

Here are my models

```
    public class DonorPledgesModel
{
    public string SE_AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }
    public string Schedule_Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Next_Payment_Date { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string Designation_Title { get; set; }
    public string Designation_Value { get; set; }
    public double Designation_Amount { get; set; }
}

    public class DonorOverviewModel
{
    public string SE_AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Org_Type { get; set; }
    public string Company_Name { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Email_Address { get; set; }
    public string Address_Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Address_Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Address_City { get; set; }
    public string Address_State { get; set; }
    public string Address_Zip { get; set; }
    public string Address_Country { get; set; }
    public string Payment_Method_Type { get; set; }
    public double Donor_Paid_Fee { get; set; }
    public List<DonorPledgesModel> Donor_Pledges { get; set; }    
}
```

Here is the part of my controller related to the models

```
                        DonorOverviewModel donor = new DonorOverviewModel();

                    using (SqlDataReader drGetDonorInfo = donorDemographicsCMD.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (drGetDonorInfo.Read())
                        {
                            donor.Address_City = drGetDonorInfo["Address_City"].ToString();
                            donor.Address_Country = drGetDonorInfo["Address_Country"].ToString();
                            donor.Address_Line1 = drGetDonorInfo["Address_Line1"].ToString();
                            donor.Address_Line2 = drGetDonorInfo["Address_Line2"].ToString();
                            donor.Address_State = drGetDonorInfo["Address_State"].ToString();
                            donor.Address_Zip = drGetDonorInfo["Address_Zip"].ToString();
                            donor.Company_Name = drGetDonorInfo["Company_Name"].ToString();
                            donor.Donor_Paid_Fee = Convert.ToDouble(drGetDonorInfo["Donor_Paid_Fee"]);
                            donor.Email_Address = drGetDonorInfo["Email_Address"].ToString();
                            donor.First_Name = drGetDonorInfo["First_Name"].ToString();
                            donor.Last_Name = drGetDonorInfo["Last_Name"].ToString();
                            donor.Org_Type = Convert.ToBoolean(drGetDonorInfo["Org_Type"]);
                            donor.Payment_Method_Type = drGetDonorInfo["Payment_Method_Type"].ToString();
                            donor.SE_AccountNumber = drGetDonorInfo["SE_AccountNumber"].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    donorPledgesCMD.Parameters.AddWithNullableValue("@accountnumber", donor.SE_AccountNumber);

                    using (SqlDataReader drGetDonorPledges = donorPledgesCMD.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (drGetDonorPledges.Read())
                        {
                            DonorPledgesModel donorPledges = new DonorPledgesModel();

                            donorPledges.SE_AccountNumber = drGetDonorPledges["SE_AccountNumber"].ToString();
                            donorPledges.Created_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(drGetDonorPledges["Created_Date"]);
                            donorPledges.Schedule_Type = drGetDonorPledges["Schedule_Type"].ToString();
                            donorPledges.Start_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(drGetDonorPledges["Start_Date"]);
                            donorPledges.Expires_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(drGetDonorPledges["Expires_Date"]);
                            donorPledges.Next_Payment_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(drGetDonorPledges["Next_Payment_Date"]);
                            donorPledges.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(drGetDonorPledges["Amount"].ToString());
                            donorPledges.Designation_Title = drGetDonorPledges["Designation_Title"].ToString();
                            donorPledges.Designation_Value = drGetDonorPledges["Designation_Value"].ToString();
                            donorPledges.Designation_Amount = Convert.ToDouble(drGetDonorPledges["Designation_Amount"].ToString());

                            donor.Donor_Pledges.Add(donorPledges);
                        }
                    }
                    return donor;
```

I've checked the values of donorPledges at the point it tries to add it to the list and it does contain the correct values.  Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you instantiating `donor.Donor_Pledges`?

Comment: Do you know what an object is, do you know what an object reference is, do you know how to create an instance of an object, do you know what a null reference is? if the duplicate doesn't answer your question, update the question with the appropriate information

Comment: @TheGeneral I read that article before posting the question last night.  I couldn't find my answer in that.  However, it was after midnight and I'd been coding all day.  I re-read the article this morning and I was able to solve the problem by changing the line `DonorOverviewModel donor = new DonorOverviewModel()` to                         `DonorOverviewModel donor = new DonorOverviewModel{ Donor_Pledges = new List<DonorPledgesModel>() }`.  I am fairly new to coding and am self taught, so if I use wrong terms I appreciate constructive feedback.  Thanks!

Comment: @insane_developer Thanks, I wasn't instantiating `donor.Donor_Pledges`.  I thought it was instantiated as part of the `DonorOverviewModel donor = new DonorOverviewModel()`.  Learned something new today. :)